# How do I include table headers when saving an NSTableView as PDF

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have the following code to save the full table (ie not just what is visible to the user) as a PDF file.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pointsTable: NSTableView!

@IBAction func saveAsPDF(_ sender: Any) {
    let headers = pointsTable.headerView?.dataWithPDF(inside: (pointsTable.headerView?.bounds)!)
    let rows = pointsTable.dataWithPDF(inside: pointsTable.bounds)

    if var data = headers{
        data.append(rows)

        let pdf = PDFDocument.init(data: data)

        if let url = OpenAndSaveDialogues().saveFilePath(suggestedFileName: "CampPoints", allowFileTypes: ["pdf"]){
            pdf?.write(to: url)
        }
    }

}
```

This successfully saves a PDF with all the information I want except the table headers are not included. In that code if I don't include the data.append(rows) then I get a PDF with just the column headers. However as soon as I append the rows data I end up with just the rows and no headers.

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a different approach to this ?

Comment: Duplicate of [Print NSTableView to PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173452/print-nstableview-to-pdf-file).

Comment: I guess so. Should I restate my question as which does the data.append method not append but instead seems to replace ?  Do I somehow remove this question.